# Como pegar uma variável de uma outra classe em Kotlin?

Tags: classes, android-activity, kotlin

Eu quero pegar uma variável de uma atividade e usá-la em outra classe. Esta variável será preenchida por um usuário em um editText chamado editTextSerie

```
 override fun searchSeries(listener: OnDataListener) {

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/")
            .build()

        val client = retrofit.create(MovieDBApiInterface::class.java)

        val objetoClasse1 = SearchActivity()

        var nomeS = objetoClasse1.editTextSerie.text.toString().trim()


        val responseCall = client.searchSeries("API_KEY", "pt-BR", nomeS)

        responseCall.enqueue(object : Callback<AllSeriesResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<AllSeriesResponse>?, response1: Response<AllSeriesResponse>?) {
                listener.onSuccess(response1!!.body()!!.results)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<AllSeriesResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {
                listener.onFailure(t!!.message.toString())
            }
        })
    }
```

Esta função "searchSeries" é da classe "Series".

Eu quero pegar o "editTextSerie" de outra classe chamada "Search Activity", então eu criei a variável "nomeS" para receber o valor dela.

```
class SearchActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var botaoSearch: AppCompatImageButton? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search)



        botaoSearch = findViewById(R.id.btn_search)

        botaoSearch?.setOnClickListener {


          var nomeSerie = editTextSerie.text.toString().trim()


        }
    }
}
```

Eu quero receber este valor (valor de `editTextSerie` vem do XML de `SearchActivity`) e usá-lo em `responseCall` com a variável "nomeS"

Comment: Coloca o código completo das classes